# A dbx warning creating issue while following fork in dbx

Tags: c, fork, dbx

I am getting some issues while following child process in dbx in a huge legacy C code. I am presenting below the code part under investigation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main()
{
    if(fork()) exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

when I run through dbx in Solaris 10, I am getting the following output:

```
Running: a.out
(process id 28193)
stopped in main at line 5 in file "a.c"
    5           if(fork()) exit(0);
(dbx) next
dbx: detected a fork(). Do you want to follow parent, child or stop to investigate?
> child
Following child ...
detaching from process 28193
Attached to process 28197
stopped in __fork1 at 0xfeefc6b7
0xfeefc6b7: __fork1+0x0007:     jb       __cerror       [ 0xfee70a40, .-0x8bc77 ]
Current function is main
    5           if(fork()) exit(0);
dbx: warning: stepping up to a function with srcline info
```

Why I am getting this warning `dbx: warning: stepping up to a function with srcline info`?

I am sorry. I re-posted this question since I didn't get any responses.

I badly need this to be worked.

Can anyone please help me over this?